# Serializing/Deserializing List into JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a list of objects across two projects I have. This is the class I'm using:

```
public class Stock
{
    public string Bin { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The part where I serialize:

```
var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Select(k => new Stock() { Article = article, Bin = k.Bin, Quantity = k.Quantity }));
```

The part where I deserialize:

```
var stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Stock>>(data);
```

This is the exception I get:

```
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DTOs.Stock].
```

This is the data that is displayed on the error page:

```
[{"Bin":"MJ11906","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":50},{"Bin":"ME04307","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":56},{"Bin":"MD08301","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":66},{"Bin":"MG12303","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":70},{"Bin":"ME04402","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":72},{"Bin":"ME12402","Article":"148400MU_","Quantity":72}]
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong, I've tried to serialize/deserialize to/from List and Ienumerable but the result is the same. Can't seem to find any Google result to solve this...

Comment: Use a list `var stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(data);`

Comment: If you want to keep it abstract you can also use `IList<>`

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to serialize/deserialize the data? Which version?

Comment: The serializing code is in a project compiled against .Net Framework 4.5, using Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.0.0 The deserializing code is in a project compiled agains .Net Core 2, using Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.0

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have different objects named `Stock` but with different namespaces? Can you confirm that the type of object you're trying to serialize is exactly the same you're trying to deserialize? I had a similar issue in the past due to different namespaces ;-)

Comment: The referenced Stock class is the same. Both projects reference the same dll

Answer (score 1):

I just created a .NET Core 2.0 console application using VS2017 (Community Edition). Code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDemo
{
    public class Stock
    {
        public string Bin { get; set; }
        public string Article { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"[{""Bin"":""MJ11906"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":50},{""Bin"":""ME04307"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":56},{""Bin"":""MD08301"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":66},{""Bin"":""MG12303"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":70},{""Bin"":""ME04402"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":72},{""Bin"":""ME12402"",""Article"":""148400MU_"",""Quantity"":72}]";

            var stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Stock>>(json);
            var stocks2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Stock>>(json);
            var stocks3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(json);
            var stocks4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stock[]>(json);

            string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stocks);

            stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Stock>>(json);
            stocks2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Stock>>(json);
            stocks3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(json);
            stocks4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stock[]>(json);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

No exceptions are being thrown. I have tried with versions 9.0.1, 10.0.1 and 11.0.2 of nuget package Newtonsoft.Json, everything works as expected.

Have you tried using updating the version of Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: I've just updated to the same version, still get the exception :/

Comment: When I define the test data and deserialize on the same method everything works fine, however when I fetch the data with HttpClient class I get the exception. Weird

Comment: @TeaWithCookies it's hard to help you without knowing more details.... You haven't mentioned the `HttpClient` before, I suggest you to post the code you're using to do the http request and deserialize the response.